# Why didn't the IGBT's output voltage change?

Tags: voltage, igbt

I have a lab experiment and we are trying to make IGBTs switch.

Here is our experiment:

[image]

In first situation, our values like that:

- 10kHz, 10V pulse
- Vcc = 15V
- Frequency=10k

And with this setup, I can observe 14V output voltage.

In second situation, we only change the pulse's voltage to 15V and the other values same. However, I observed the same output voltage as 14V.

What's the explanation of that? Why did the output voltage stay the same?

By the way: I used Proteus to simulate this circuit.

Comment: That sounds normal. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Andyaka I know it's normal but why? I mean why I'm observing the same output voltages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *In second situation, we only change the pulse's voltage to 15V and the
> other values same. However, I observed the same output voltage as 14V.*

If the 10 volt gate signal is enough to adequately turn on and off the IGBT and deliver 14 volts p-p from a 15 volt power rail then, increasing the gate drive voltage isn't going to improve much on this situation.

> *What's the explanation of that? Why did the output voltage stay the
> same?*

The output p-p voltage can never exceed the power rail of 15 volts (unless you are using a transformer or an inductor which you aren't) so, given that the IGBT saturation level will be about 1 volt (when fully active), you won't get any significant improvement from 14 volts p-p on the output by raising the amplitude of the gate drive signal.

Comment: thanks for your awesome comment :)

Comment: @sonelektrikci [Do you know what to do next?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png). If you are happy with this answer then you now know what to do. If you still have questions on this subject, leave another comment.

Comment: I couldnt vote somehow